# RAD Studio conditional breakpoint causing E2018

Tags: delphi, debugging, breakpoints, delphi-xe5

Im trying to stop on a breakpoint iff the variable im investigating is bigger than 0.

```
Directory.length > 0;
```

All I get is Error message E2018.

Comment: Did you read the documentation about `E2018` error? Did you include the `System.SysUtils` (StringHelper)? Try to use `Length( Directory ) > 0`

Comment: System.SysUtils are included. However your rewrite of my function worked. Thanks.

Comment: Then I guess that you cannot use record helpers for breakpoints. Followed by the documentation [All symbols in the expression must be accessible from the breakpoint's location](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Add_Address_Breakpoint_or_Add_Data_Breakpoint) I would say this is a bug

Comment: Sir Rufo please post your respone as an answer so that I can set it as 'the' answer.